# Is pointer function receiver with nil safe?

Tags: go

On hovering over `t1.Print()`, my IDE complains:

> Receiver 't' may be 'nil' in call

and in more detail:

> Method calls with 'nil' receiver could lead to 'nil pointer dereference'

But after playing around with the code, I can't seem to get a `nil pointer dereference error`. What am I missing? How can I cause that error?

```
type T []string

func (t *T) Print() {
    log.Print(t)
    log.Print(*t)
    log.Print(&t)
    log.Print(&(*t))
}

func main() {
    var t1 T
    t1.Print()
}
```

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/2pqSWNJ3X5n Using a pointer receiver is safe if the receiver is initialized, calling a method on an uninitialized pointer receiver, i.e. `nil`, is also safe as long as you don't try to dereference the pointer. Using pointer receivers is very common, personally I don't get what the IDE is trying to say apart from the obvious and I would just ignore it.

Comment: `T` is not a pointer type. Try `var t1 *T`.

Comment: @Peter T is actually a pointer type in golang: it points to a slice and can be initialized to nil `var t1 T = nil` or `t1 := T(nil)`. `var t1 *T` is a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: @Imaxd `T` is not a pointer type, it's a slice type. `*T` is a pointer type, pointer to slice.

Comment: @Peter Indeed a slice is a reference (not pointer) type (like maps). My point is that you don't need to pass a slice by pointer or have a pointer receiver to a slice.

Comment: @Imaxd, yes, you do need to use a pointer to get a pointer receiver. And your program does: [the compiler rewrites the method call](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls) to `(&t1).Print()` and &t1 is of type *T, but that's not a nil pointer. It's an initialized pointer that points to a nil slice.

Comment: @Peter No you don't need a pointer to T to have a method on T that take a pointer receiver. https://play.golang.com/p/0J7Y5mwUcYp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not getting a nil pointer dereference error because there is no nil pointer in this program.

`var t1 T` initializes a value of type `T`, which is not a pointer type. Because the Print method has a pointer receiver, the method call `t1.Print()` is automatically rewritten to `(&t1).Print()`

> A method call x.m() is valid if the method set of (the type of) x contains m and the argument list can be assigned to the parameter list of m. If x is addressable and &x's method set contains m, x.m() is shorthand for (&x).m()

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls

`&t1` is of type *T, which is a pointer type, but the pointer is not nil. Perhaps this is confusing at a glance because t1 is in fact nil (a nil slice), but it is perfectly legal to address a nil slice:

```
type T []string

func main() {
    var t1 T

    fmt.Println(t1 == nil)  // true (nil slice)
    fmt.Println(&t1 == nil) // false (non-nil pointer to nil slice)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/i-I0PYsjLew

To provoke a panic the receiver itself must be nil (instead of pointing to some nil value):

```
type T []string

func (t *T) Print() {
    log.Print(t)
    log.Print(*t) // panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
}

func main() {
    var t1 *T // nil pointer
    t1.Print()
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/9whVZgeAGnI

Note that the panic occurs inside the method, not where the method is called. This is different from other languages such as Java, C++, C# where a method call constitutes a pointer dereference. That's not the case in Go.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation @Peter.